# Existence of an inner point in a nonempty polyhedron

Tags: linear-algebra, polyhedra, integer-programming, polytopes

I was reading some notes on polyhedral analysis and encountered a proof that confused me. The proof is in the book named "Integer and Combinatorial Optimization" by Wolsey and Nemhauser.

Let $M = \{l, 2, ... , m\}, M^{=} = \{i \in M: a_ix = b_i, \forall x \in  P\}$ and let $M^{\leq} = M \setminus M^{=}$ where $P$ is a rational polyhedron.

$Definition:$ A point $x \in P$ called an inner point  of $P$ if $a^ix < b_i , \forall i \in M^{\leq}$.

$Proposition:$ Every nonempty polyhedron has an inner point.

$Proof:$ If $M^{\leq} = \emptyset$, every point of $P$ is inner. Otherwise, for $i \in M^{\leq}$ there exists a point $x^i \in P$ with $a^i x^i < b_i$ . Now $ \hat{x}= (1 / |M^{\leq}|)\sum_{i \in M^{\leq}}x^i \in P$ since $P$ is convex. Since $a^i \hat{x} < b_i, \forall i \in M^{\leq}$, $\hat{x}$ is an inner point.

Doesn't the second statement (*Otherwise, for $i \in M^{\leq}$ there exists a point $x^i \in P$ with $a^i x^i < b_i$*) imply that we already assume that there exists an inner point? If that is the case, why do we show that there exist $\hat{x}$ satifying the condition of an inner point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is a *different* $x^i$ for every $i.$ But we want **the same** $x$ for every $i.$ The proof constructs such an $x.$ On the other hand, I don't think the construction works, since while $\hat{x} \in P,$ I don't really see why $\hat{x}$ satisfies all the strict inequalities.

Comment: How do we show that $\hat{x}$ satisfies each $a^i \hat{x} < b_i$? I can see that $\hat{x} \in P$. How does that guarantee that none of the inequalities is satisfied at equality?

Comment: @whitepanda I edited the answer just as you were typing the comment - the proof seems wrong.

Comment: Okay, I guess I did figure it out. Since each $x^i \in P$, those solutions are feasible meaning that each $a^i x< b_i$ inequality must be satisfied at either equality or strict inequality. When we set $\hat{x}$ as the convex combinations of those feasible points, that guarantees that each inequality is satisfied strictly.

Comment: @whitepanda Why? What do the $a$s and the $b$s have to do with $P?$

Comment: Well, $P$ is the polyhedron defined as $P = \{ Ax \leq b \}$ where $M$ represent the set of rows in $A$. Then, we construct $M^{=}$ and $M^{\leq}$ out of $A$. For example, let $P$ be $x_1\leq 3, x_2 \leq 1$. Then, let us pick $x^1 = [2,1]$ and $x^2 = [0 ,0]$. We can set $\hat{x} = [1, 0.5]$ which would be an inner point.

Comment: Ah, OK, you did not give the definition. Then, ok.